# What do square brackets, "[]", mean in function/class documentation?

Tags: python

I am having trouble figuring out the arguments to csv.dictreader and realized I have no clue what the square brackets signify.

From the docmentation:

```
class csv.DictReader(csvfile[, fieldnames=None[, restkey=None[, restval=None[, dialect='excel'[, *args, **kwds]]]]])
```

I'd appreciate a summary of the arguments to the class instantiation.

Thanks

Comment: related: [How to read API documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10925478/1048572)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does \[, element\] mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752417/what-does-element-mean)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The square brackets indicate that these arguments are **optional**. You can leave them out.

So, in this case you are only *required* to pass the `csvfile` argument to `csv.DictReader`. If you would pass a second parameter, it would be interpreted as the `fieldnames` arguments. The third would be `restkey`, etc.

If you only want to specify e.g. `cvsfile` and `dialect`, then you'll have to name the keyword argument explicitly, like so:

```
csv.DictReader(file('test.csv'), dialect='excel_tab')
```

For more on keyword arguments, see [section 4.7.2](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) of the tutorial at python.org.

Comment: This answer is correct.  There's just one thing I would add.

Although cvs.DictReader takes keyword arguments, you can have non-keyword arguments with defaults too.  These tend to be in builtin functions written in C, like the global 'range()' function, or the 'split()' method on a string.

The documentation for 'split' on a string gives its arguments like this:

S.split([sep, [,maxsplit]]) -> list of strings

You might therefore think this would work:

"a b c d e f g".split(maxsplit=2)

but, sadly, it doesn't.  Python throws an "TypeError: split() takes no keyword arguments" exception.  Sigh.

Comment: Is there a difference between optional versus default arguements?  What would be the difference between:
def exampleFunc1(arg1, [arg2 = 2], [arg3 = 3]):
and
def exampleFunc2(arg1, arg2 = 2, arg3 = 3):

Thanks

Comment: @behindalens: in both cases `arg2` and `arg3` can be omitted, in which case their value would be `2` and `3`, respectively. Optional *arguments* can have a default *value*.

Comment: Is there any significance in the fact that the square brackets are nested?

Comment: @behindalens: it more clearly conveys how unnamed optional arguments are interpreted. I suppose the unnested version could mean something else, namely that these optional arguments *must* be named because there is no clear ordering (so you'd have to write e.g. `arg2=7`), but then the second comma should be inside the brackets if you ask me: `exampleFunc1(arg1, [arg2 = 2,] [arg3 = 3])`. (But again, perhaps that's just me.) In general, my advice is to carefully read the documentation, and when in doubt just write some test code. That's what I do :)

Comment: @Stephan202: To summarize, nesting square brackets indicates some order in the optional arguments. Is this usually standard for similar language documentation?

Comment: Yes, you'll also find this notation elsewhere, e.g. in manpages (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page)

Answer (score 2):

Usually in api documentation square brackets mean optional. I would think they mean the same here.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a subset of the widely used notation to unambiguously describe language syntax called [Backus-Naur Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) (see Wikipedia article for details).

Answer (score 1):

To reiterate what the others have said, the arguments are optional.

If you leave out optional parts, the remaining `fieldnames=`, `restval=`, `restkey=` or `dialect=` keywords tell the function which parts are missing.

The syntax doesn't suggest it, but I wouldn't be surprised if the keywords allow the arguments to be specificied in any order, except that the last two arguments must be either both specified, or both omitted.

Comment: Indeed keyword arguments can be specified in any order. That's (part of) their appeal. Also, functions which take arbitrarily many keyword arguments do so with the `**kwargs` parameter, which is a `dict`. As you know, `dict` objects do not maintain order.

Comment: @pavium: How is it indicated that the last two arguments **both** be specified or omitted?

Comment: They are *both* inside a single set of brackets.