# How to understand pydoc parameters in documentation

Tags: python, pydoc

I was looking up `seek()` in `pydoc file` and found the explanation on what the function does, but I didn't understand how the documentation states the parameters.  It looked like this:

```
seek(offset[, whence])
```

At first I thought it was a parameter in a parameter but it obviously isn't.  What do those brackets denote in the parameter fields?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read API documentation for newbs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925478/how-to-read-api-documentation-for-newbs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

everything that is between `[` and `]` are optional

in this case you can call:

```
seek(offset)
```

or

```
seek(offset, whence)
```