# Reading incomplete API docs - how do you know what all your [options] are if they are not listed?

Tags: node.js, api, mongoose

How do you go about finding all the `[options]` available to you when they are not listed out?

In the case of `mongoose` for `nodejs`:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-index

Examples help but are not often complete. How does one track down the full extent of the `options` you can pass in as the second parameter?

**It reads**:

```
Schema#index(fields, [options])

Defines an index (most likely compound) for this schema.

show code
Parameters:

fields <Object>
[options] <Object>
Example

schema.index({ first: 1, last: -1 }, { unique: true })
```

In some places, all the options are detailed out, which is wonderful.
example:

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#connection_Connection-openSet

Thanks.

Also, I found this lovely question/answer.

[How to read API documentation for newbs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925478/how-to-read-api-documentation-for-newbs)

Comment: One of the best way to find out what options (indeed any functionality) are available is to look at the tests.

Comment: Smart suggestion. So, I just go to source code into the tests. Got it.

Comment: This is assuming they write good tests though ;) in the case of this project you'll be fine: https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/master/test/schema.test.js#L1028

Comment: Nice. Thanks for pointing to the place. So, the options are (did I miss any?): unique: Boolean, sparse: Boolean, expireAfterSeconds: Number, type: <type> (eg. String,Date,Number.._, expires: String (eg. '24h'), background: Boolean

Comment: Yup that looks right, but be careful the index options are dependent on the Type: https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/master/lib/schematype.js#L96

Comment: Got it. They put more documentation into the doc string than in the api docs. :D Now I know to look at the doc string of the tests AND the tests.

Comment: By the way, if you want to write that up in the answer, I'd accept because I think when the API docs are incomplete, the only way to understand more is to introspect the code, and the easiest first step is indeed look at the tests.

Comment: Thanks I've posted our conversation as an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious answer is to read through the source code, but frequently I've found it's often easier to read the tests. The tests will often be the bits of code that the developer(s) cares about.

In the case of Schema Index the tests alluded to several options: https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/master/test/schema.test.js#L1028

However after further digging a lot of the options were tied to a specific schema type: https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/master/lib/schematype.js#L96