# What does this mean in documentation: square bracket followed by comma ( [, )

Tags: php, jquery

Today this caught my attention on [jQuery's API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) for the `closest` selector:

```
.closest( selector [, context ] )
```

What exactly does `[, context]` mean? I know I can put a variable or jQuery object there to set as the context. This itself isn't entirely clear to me, **but the part in particular I'm asking about today is the square bracket comma ( `[,` )**. What does this mean? I've also seen similar notation on [php.net's manual pages](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php).

```
bool ob_start ([ callable $output_callback [, int $chunk_size = 0 [, ...
```

Is there some preliminary lesson I've missed? because this is greek to me and I can't be the only one who's looked at this and thought "WTF..." but ignored it and went on guessing, when I could have saved a lot of time...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925478/how-to-read-api-documentation-for-newbs/14362141#14362141

Comment: I looked for this question a lot, so sorry if I didn't find it. Do either have __ nevermind i see it in that question

Comment: @Jamil: No, the formatting is pretty standard — you just have to guess. (Well, apart from the occasional general documentation formatting advice, like in the linked question.)

Comment: I have this exact question too! I wonder why they don't simply write [var] just as linux man page does. What's the point to put a comma in it?

Comment: Thanks for the question! You saved my life! I was going to ask the exact same question about `[, arguments]` because I am sure I am not the only one who got confused about this and looking this syntax definition across the internet turns out to be difficult.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means that parameter is *optional*. You don't have to provide it and if you don't it will use the value you see listed there by *default*.

Answer (score 3):

Funnily enough, there's a dedicated page in the PHP manual on [how to read a function definition](http://www.php.net/manual/en/about.prototypes.php). So, quoting the mentioned page:

> All optional parameters are seen in *[* brackets *]*.

Also, manual's "[About the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/about.php)" is an interesting read, if you are into that.