# Git Command Format?

Tags: git, version-control

Git commands are given in this format

```
'git pull' [options] [<repository> [<refspec>...]]
```

What is meant by the brackets? Are these optional statements?

Comment: Yes, as in any other language spec.

Comment: Where can I read more about the formst of language/command specifications? I feel like this isnt something that is gone over in detail very often.

Comment: You may want to look at [How to read API documentation for newbs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925478/how-to-read-api-documentation-for-newbs).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, those flags are optional, you can simply run:

```
git pull
```

and it will pull the latest from your current repo.

:)