# documentation function parameter notation meaning

Tags: javascript, notation, rangy

I have a question about what a particular set of notation means. I am using the rangy javascript library to do some work and I often run across the notation

```
rangy.createClassApplier(String theClass[, Object options[, Array tagNames]])
```

How do i interpret the parameter notation. In particular the "[," notation confuses me. I'm guessing it means those parameters are optional but I'm not sure and I've had a hard time finding an answer to this question online. Thanks in advance

here is a link to the documentation itself

https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki/Class-Applier-Module

Comment: You're correct. I've added a note to the documentation to explain. There are other Stack Overflow questions about this too. Here's one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925478/how-to-read-api-documentation-for-newbs

Comment: Thanks Tim! Your library is amazingly useful.