# Function parameter that includes "[," meaning

Tags: javascript

i've seen this syntax `[,` everywhere and have no idea what it implies.

```
 d3.mean(array[, accessor])

.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )
```

Why is the comma after the opening bracket? What does it mean?

Comment: the function parameters that are encased in square brackets are *optional*, omit the brackets from your code.  the brackets are only used for documentation purposes.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925478/how-to-read-api-documentation-for-newbs

Comment: Glenn should add the comment as an answer, you know, for the glory and the money...:P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comma is a separator between parameters. The square brackets mean that the parameter is optional.

So, when you read something like this:

```
.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )
```

You can know that you have multiple options of how to call this function:

```
.on(events, handler)
.on(events, selector, handler)
.on(events, selector, data, handler)
```

Answer (score 1):

It just means that the **parameters are optional**.

But be careful! These `square brackets` are just used in the documentation.