# What is [, ... ] in function/method documentation?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have come across this type of syntax in Node.js. Can anyone please explain what `[,` is in Node.js/JavaScript?

Examples of syntax I have seen.

- `assert(value[, message])`
- `const name1 = value1 [, name2 = value2 [, ... [, nameN = valueN]]];`

Comment: indicates optional

Comment: Optional parameters in documentation.

Comment: Related: [How to read API documentation for newbs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925478/how-to-read-api-documentation-for-newbs)

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Thank you for your information. Actually I do not know that it is a convention in documentation. I thought it is a part of JavaScript syntax. So I asked here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking at function definitions in documentation, and what you're seeing is a conventional way to show that one or more parameters are optional. It is not actually valid JavaScript syntax.

For example, `assert(value[, message])` means that the `value` parameter is required, but `message` is optional. You could not actually put `assert(value[, message])` in your code; it would trigger a syntax error.

Comment: Thank you. I cannot find the same in google search because google ignores the special characters. So I asked here.