# indexOf fromIndex function?

Tags: javascript

I am just wondering what is the use of formIndex ofstring.indexOf(searchValue[, fromIndex])? I found a code like this:

```
 for (var sA in secondOnArray) { 
  if (firstOnArray.indexOf(secondOnArray[sA]) > -1) { // what is the purpose of [sA] there?
   result+= 0; 
  }
 }
```

[Mozilla String indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) and [w3Schools indexOf()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) examples seems very different?

Comment: "*what is the purpose of [sA] there*" [`for..in` loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) iterate through key/property names, in this case assigned to `sA`. The value still needs to be accessed.

Comment: Related: [How to read API documentation for newbs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925478/how-to-read-api-documentation-for-newbs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the notation.

```
ofstring.indexOf(searchValue[, fromIndex])
```

This means that the second argument to this function, `fromIndex`, is optional. If provided, it tells `indexOf` where to start looking. Otherwise, it is defaulted to `0`.

To call the two-argument form, the syntax is:

```
ofstring.indexOf(value, index)
```

and note in particular that there are no square brackets. The square brackets are just a notational convenience for the documentation.

As for why the square brackets are there in your code, note that `sA` in the below code is an index. So to obtain the *value* of `secondOnArray` at index `sA`, we need to index it, hence the square brackets. This is unrelated to the two-argument form of `indexOf`.

```
for (var sA in secondOnArray) { 
  if (firstOnArray.indexOf(secondOnArray[sA]) > -1) {
    result += 0; 
  }
}
```

One might consider writing instead

```
secondOnArray.forEach(function (ele) {
  if (firstOnArray.indexOf(ele) > -1) {
    result += 0;
  }
});
```

which specifies the intention clearer.

Comment: I really admire your answer, I am just wondering how did you master javascript? javascript is very hard to understand I am on free code camp now, any advise?

Comment: @GlendonPhilippBaculio As with most languages, practice makes perfect. Aside from that, I recommend the [MDN Tutorials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) if you have not seen those already.

Comment: thank you for your recommendation. I am on free code camp now and I must say it's a very hard start, I will be going to check that,