# JavaScript API documentation - what does functionName([value[, arguments]]) notation mean?

Tags: javascript, api, d3.js

This question is related to: [How to read API documentation for newbs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925478/how-to-read-api-documentation-for-newbs). However, that question does not cover the specific format I am asking about here where there are nested brackets (for example, `[value[, args]]`).

Although, I presume this could relate to any API, I'm looking at the D3.js API, specifically [`transition.ease()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Transitions.md#ease). I cannot figure out what the following means:

```
transition.ease([value[, arguments]])
```

It's difficult to find out, as I don't know what search terms to Google! I just want to know:

1. How it is suppose to be read?
2. Is it a general/normal notation?

I know how to use that D3 function; it's just the notation I'm interested in.

Comment: likely value is optional, and if value is supplied, then arguments is optional.

Comment: @georg don't think it's a duplicate, as I'm asking about a very specific notation [x[,x]], that is not covered in that duplicate question/answer. Mayken answer below covers this

Comment: I agree that, while closely related, the question linked as duplicate does not cover the specific case of nested optional arguments. The most up-voted answer to that question covers option notation well. While this question is an extension of that notation, it is clear that you, and others, do not find it to be intuitive. A good idea would be to [edit] this question to link to that question & describe why/how the "answers do not fully address your question". After all, the text about duplicate questions states that if that is the case then another question should be asked (e.g. this question).

Comment: If you include in the question such a link and text with an explanation as to why this is not a duplicate, I would vote to re-open this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for [`transition.ease([value[, arguments]])`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Transitions.md#ease) appears to make it relatively clear what they are attempting to say. In addition, it follows the "normal" syntax for methods of having optional arguments in `[]`.

In this case, it means that `ease()` is a method of `transition`.  For the `ease()` method: `([value[, arguments]])`, means passing any arguments is optional. Then, `value[, arguments]` is intended to mean that if the `value` argument is present, then an unrestricted number of additional `arguments` may optionally be present. I say "intended to mean" because normally being able to have multiples of an argument is indicated using an ellipse `...`. Thus, that would normally be: `value[, arguments...]`. From looking further at the documentation, it is clear that this is what was intended.

Parsing the documentation (additional formatting by me):

> Specifies the transition [easing function](http://www.robertpenner.com/easing/).
>
> If *value* is a function, it is used to ease the current parametric timing value *t*, which is typically in the range [0,1]. (At the end of a transition, *t* may be slightly greater than 1.)

You can pass a function as the argument to `transition.ease()`.  If you do, then it is used as the function to determine how the transition occurs.

> Otherwise, *value* is assumed to be a string and the arguments are passed to the [d3.ease](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Transitions.md#d3_ease) method to generate an easing function. The default easing function is "cubic-in-out". Note that it is not possible to customize the easing function per-element or per-attribute; however, if you use the "linear" easing function, you can apply custom easing inside your interpolator using [attrTween](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Transitions.md#attrTween) or [styleTween](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Transitions.md#styleTween).

If `value` is not a function, it is assumed that you are going to use [`d3.ease()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Transitions.md#d3_ease) as the transition function. In which case, all the arguments to `transition.ease()` are passed to `d3.ease()`. `d3.ease()` assumes that `value` (called `type` in the `d3.ease()` write-up) is a string. [`d3.ease(type[, arguments…])`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Transitions.md#d3_ease) has the ability to take additional optional arguments. In order for you to specify any additional arguments you desire to the `d3.ease()` function, `transition.ease()` also has the ability to accept such arguments and pass them to `d3.ease()`.

Note: Looking at the interaction between `transition.ease()` and `d3.ease()` is where we see that `transition.ease([value[, arguments]])` really should have been written with the ellipse as `transition.ease([value[, arguments..]])`. If that is not the intended use, then the described interaction with `d3.ease()` would not make sense.

> If *ease* is not specified, returns the easing function bound to the first non-null element in the transition.

This is actually not clear. I expect that it contains a mistake in that "*ease*" should be "*value*". In which case it would read:

> If *value* is not specified, returns the easing function bound to the first non-null element in the transition.

If this is actually what was intended, then not specifying any arguments to `transition.ease()` will result in getting back as a returned value the easing function which is bound to the first non-null element in the transition.  This would be a normal and expected use of not supplying any arguments to such a function.  Thus, I consider that it is quite likely that this issue really is a mistake in the documentation.  This could be verified by either looking in the source code, or by experimentation.

Comment: Thanks. That's a great explanation. I was pretty sure that based just on the [value[,params]] that it is not possible to know what is required. With just that notation, you could not deduce that if value is not a function, it expects a string. I thought it was a generic way of writing api doc, but it's not

Answer (score -1):

It means `value` and `arguments` are optional.