# what's the meaning of '[,params_name]' in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is node.js document about [response.writeHead(statusCode[, statusMessage][, headers])](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_writehead_statuscode_statusmessage_headers;)

I don't understand "statusCode[, statusMessage][, headers]",

Is it stand for one params or more?

- if one, why `writeHead(200,` followed a comma?

  if two, why `statusCode[, statusMessage][, headers]` without a
  comma?

where means I can pass json?

Is there any document show about these param's rule?

**Example:**

```
const body = 'hello world';
response.writeHead(200, {
  'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(body),
  'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
```

Comment: the [] mean those arguments are optional. Also writeHead() is for writing the headers not writing the content.

Comment: Related: [How to read API documentation ...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925478/how-to-read-api-documentation-for-newbs)

Comment: @JonathanLonowski. Is it stand for one params or more?

Comment: @Albert.Qing The brackets aren't part of the code you write. They're only relevant within the documentation and are intended to briefly suggest which arguments are required or optional. In this case, an argument for `statusCode` is required, but arguments for either `statusMessage` or `headers` are not. – So, `.writeHead(200)`, `.writeHead(200, 'OK')`, `.writeHead(200, { Age: 12 })`, etc. are valid uses.

Comment: Is there any document show about these rules? stil very confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule is simple - square brackets surrounding any text mean "this text is optional". So

```
response.writeHead(statusCode[, statusMessage][, headers])
```

Means all of the following

```
response.writeHead(statusCode, statusMessage, headers)
response.writeHead(statusCode, statusMessage)
response.writeHead(statusCode, headers)
response.writeHead(statusCode)
```

---

If the square brackets were nested as

```
response.writeHead(statusCode[, statusMessage[, headers]])
```

it means all of:

```
response.writeHead(statusCode, statusMessage, headers)
response.writeHead(statusCode, statusMessage)
response.writeHead(statusCode)
```

Noting that removing the outer set also results in the inner set being removed

Comment: Good explanation!