# What do parameters of React.Component.setState() mean syntactically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax

Currently I'm reading the documentation of React and I don't understand what do the following parameters mean syntactically in [`setState()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) method:

```
setState(updater[, callback])
```

I tried to use [Esprima parser](http://esprima.org/demo/parse.html?code=setState(updater%5B%2C%20callback%5D)) to perform syntatical analysis in order to determine what are those but it shows syntactical error for the line of code.

Comment: Remove the `[]`...

Comment: `setState({ someItem: true })` or `setState(state => ({counter: state.counter + 1})`. Use the latter when referencing state to derive the next state (it's good practice). You rarely need to use the callback it's for edge cases.

Comment: @Nope: It is stated in the documentation

Comment: @Isaac In documentation brackets denote optional parameters if the parser can't deal with that, it's not the documentations fault I'd reckon [**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925478/how-to-read-api-documentation-for-newbs**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925478/how-to-read-api-documentation-for-newbs)

Comment: setState() function is async that's why we pass callback function in setState() function,
If you want to update your state you should do - > this.setState({stateName:data})
If you want to update your state and there is another dependancy on that updated state so while doing this
this.setState({stateName:data})
this.newData(this.state.stateName);
Due to asynch nature it send will old state data  in newData(), to make sure updated data pass in newData() , you should do this - > 
this.setState({stateName:data},()=>{this.newData(this.state.stateName)})