# What does square bracket mean in python paramters

Tags: python-3.x

Hello I'm new to python and I'm trying to learn OpenCV.
When I check the API references for OpenCV I came across this types of parameter description.

```
cv2.imread(filepath[, flags])
```

What does the "[, flags]" part mean? I know it takes in two variable, which is **filepath** and **flags**, but I don't know the meaning of the square bracket. 
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Second parameter is optional.

Comment: So is it the same as **kwargs or *kwargs ? But why is the left square bracket on the left of the comma anyway?

Comment: Because if you don't provide the second argument, you don't have to type the comma either?

Comment: @Steven97102 To be clear it's only a documentation thing, not code. You might also encounter functions expecting a parameter to have a specific value, in that case the choices you have can be written like this `a|b|c`.

Comment: This is common notation in documentation for many programming languages. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925478/how-to-read-api-documentation-for-newbs)