# Node docs syntax for function arguments?

Tags: node.js

I'm going through the node.js docs [here](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#streams-promises-api).

I'm having trouble understanding the syntax in which the arguments to functions are defined. Here's one example of many:

```
stream.pipeline(source[, ...transforms], destination[, options])
```

How can I learn more about reading the syntax in the docs?

Example questions:

- What does `[, ...transforms]` mean?
- What does `[, options]` mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to interpret function parameters in software and language documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925478/how-to-interpret-function-parameters-in-software-and-language-documentation)