# What does [, element] mean?

Tags: python

I was reading the python documentation where I came across `elem [,n]` this notation for arguments. I have seen such notations in past. Don't just know what they mean. Also, google doesn't support searching brackets.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html
Same use of brackets here.

Comment: related: [How to read API documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10925478/1048572)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Python documentation has a [section about the used notation](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/introduction.html#notation), which says:

> […] a phrase enclosed in square brackets (`[ ]`) means zero or one occurrences (in other words, the enclosed phrase is optional).

This notation originates from the [Backus–Naur Form (BNF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form).

Answer (score 5):

It means that the argument so bracketed is optional.

Answer (score 0):

Generally this means that the parameter within the square brackets is optional; however, without a link to the specific documentation it's hard to say.